# Bad idea to put a dom operation inside a redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, anti-patterns, redux-reducers

I have several actions which use the same reducer, and instead of having a dom operation in each of those actions, I want to just  add it once inside my shared reducer. I know reducers are to be pure (which the returned data still is), but is this some kind of anti-pattern or an acceptable strategy?

````
 case APPEND_POSTS:
      !payload.length &&
        document.getElementById('posts-cont').classList.add('no-more-posts'); // this 
      const total = state.posts.length + payload.length;
      const limit = total > posts_to_keep_limit ? 50 : 0;
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts.slice(limit), ...payload],
        loading: false,
      };
    ```
````

Comment: it looks bad... you should change the class with state

Comment: DOM operations should (98% of the cases) be avoided even in components, let alone in reducers. If some effect must be run alongside actions, put them inside action creators or as middlewares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redux Action

```
 case APPEND_POSTS:
      // you don't need to use below code.
      // !payload.length && document.getElementById('posts-cont').classList.add('no-more-posts'); // this 
      const total = state.posts.length + payload.length;
      const limit = total > posts_to_keep_limit ? 50 : 0;
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts.slice(limit), ...payload],
        nomore: true,
        loading: false,
      };
```

Your component.

```
function YourComp(props){
  const state = useSelector(...); 

  return ( <div id="posts-cont" className={state.nomore ? 'no-more-posts' : ''} > {...}</div>

 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know reducers are to be pure (which the returned data still is), but is this some kind of anti-pattern or an acceptable strategy?

The returned data is pure, but you've introduced a side-effect in the form of a DOM mutation. Therefore, this reducer is not pure.

This is indeed an anti-pattern because now, the component(s) that render `posts-cont` items have an invisible coupling to this reducer. It makes your codebase more difficult to read and debug.

Answer (score 1):

jinongun's advice is good: let the className of the component derive its value from the store's state using a selector. AS for the general question

> I have several actions which use the same reducer, and instead of
> having a dom operation in each of those actions, I want to just add it
> once inside my shared reducer.

DON'T EVER make DOM operations inside a reducer.
Don't ever make any operation that is not a pure computation.

But you can create an action creator that always calls a side effect (with [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)):

```
function appendPosts(payload) {
  return dispatch => {
    mySideEffect()

    dispatch({
      type: APPEND_POSTS,
      payload
    })
  }
}

function action1(params) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ACTION1,
      payload: params
    })    

    dispatch(appendPosts(params))
  }
}

function action2(params) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ACTION2,
      payload: params
    })    

    dispatch(appendPosts(params))
  }
}

// etc
```